# Scipy KDTree() Get rectagular shaped neighbouring grid points

Tags: python, scipy, kdtree

I've come across a small problem while using this module. In fact, the module does exactly what I'm asking him to do... which is finding all the nearest grid points for given coordinates among this grid.

But, when the given coordinates are very close to a point of the grid and the grid has longer steps on one side, it gives something like :

[image: scipy.spatial.KDtree results]

So in this image, the point to calculate nearest neighbor is the red dot you can see in the bottom left corner. The results given by KDTree are the blue squares. The green diamond is the 4th point I would like to get instead of the lone blue one at the top of the image.

Code :

```
>>> grid.head()
          x         y
0  0.000000 -9.490125
1  0.959131 -9.490125
2  1.918263 -9.490125
3  2.877394 -9.490125
4  3.836526 -9.490125

>>> pt
[4.0092010999999998e-05, -9.4901299629261011]

>>>tree = ssp.KDTree(grid)
>>>dis, idx = tree.query(pt,4)

>>> idx 
array([  0,  71,   1, 142])

>>> grid.iloc[idx]
            x         y
0    0.000000 -9.490125
71   0.000000 -8.980481
1    0.959131 -9.490125
142  0.000000 -8.470837
```

### Question:

Is there a way to specify that we want a rectangle shaped array in the query or something? Maybe by specifying that we only want 2 y's for one x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us ***try*** to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x0, dx = 0, 0.959131
>>> x  = np.arange(x0, x0+5*dx,dx) 
>>> y0, dy = -9.4901299629261011, 8.980481-8.470837
>>> y  = np.arange(y0, y0+2*dy,dy)
>>> data = np.transpose([np.tile(x, len(y)), np.repeat(y, len(x))])
>>> grid = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['x', 'y'])
>>> grid.head()
          x        y
0  0.000000 -9.49013
1  0.959131 -9.49013
2  1.918262 -9.49013
3  2.877393 -9.49013
4  3.836524 -9.49013
```

where `grid.head()` is based on the numerical equivalent of `grid`'s graphic representation

```
>>> grid
           x         y
0   0.000000 -9.490130 # the red dot
1   0.959131 -9.490130 # the bottom right blue square
2   1.918262 -9.490130
3   2.877393 -9.490130
4   3.836524 -9.490130
5   0.000000 -8.980486 # the middle left blue square
6   0.959131 -8.980486 # the green diamond
7   1.918262 -8.980486
8   2.877393 -8.980486
9   3.836524 -8.980486
10  0.000000 -8.470842 # the unwanted top left blue square
11  0.959131 -8.470842
12  1.918262 -8.470842
13  2.877393 -8.470842
14  3.836524 -8.470842
```

Thus, you want the points `1`, `5` and `6` as neighborhood of point `0`.

To do so, you may want to have a look at the function `kneighbors_graph` of [the sklearn.neighbors module which implements the k-nearest neighbors algorithm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph.html). Playing with it, and setting the power parameter for the [Minkowski metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance), `p`, greater than `2`, say `3` (the idea of taking `p>2` is basically to reduce the euclidean squareroot-of-2 factor -- between diagonals and sides in a unit square -- toward 1), as follows

```
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph
>>> _3n_graph = kneighbors_graph(grid,
                                 n_neighbors=3,
                                 p=3,
                                 mode='connectivity',
                                 include_self=False)
```

yields

```
>>> grid.iloc[_3n_graph[0].indices]
          x         y
5  0.000000 -8.980486
1  0.959131 -9.490130
6  0.959131 -8.980486
```

Comment: Oh my! I'm sorry for not giving you feedback earlier. For some reasons i didn't get notified you replied ! Great answer ! Finally (the project is now done), I went with a more "global" approach if i might: I used [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) instead of implementing my own way of interpolating data based on a grid.

P.S. Sorry for the non minimal, complete and verifiable example

Comment: @Alex It seems that you actually turned your rectangular grid into a square one, don't you ? So that, even with euclidean distances, you got the points you wanted.

Comment: From what I understand, the scipy griddata can take pretty much anything as an entry grid, so I left untouched what I had.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because even if I modified my code, it still answers the question I asked ! Thanks again